# see git log of commits between master and live branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, diff, git-diff

I've been scouring stackoverflow and other forums to find the answer to no avail - nothing seems to fit quite what I'm looking for.

So the issue is as follows:
I have a *master-branch* and a *live-branch*. Development continues on the *master-branch*, and when commits are deemed appropriate, they are cherry picked into the *live-branch*.

However, I discovered that the *live-branch* has a bug, which is fixed in *master-branch* and I'm trying to find which commit in *master-branch* introduced the fix.

I'm trying to do this by first seeing what the commit difference is between master and live. Some commits in master didn't make it into live, which ones?

I tried the following:

```
git log --cherry-pick --oneline --no-merges --right-only live-branch..master
```

but I don't really understand this command, this tells me the commit difference, but this gives me the same commits which are in live and master, just the hashes are different.

I need sort of a patch-like way of doing this. git diff commit_from_master,v3.8 if empty ignore.

How can I do this?

I'll update if more clarification is needed.

Comment: Consider using `git bisect`

Comment: this will take way too long, this is a large project that takes hours to compile, need commit diff...

Comment: `--right-only` requires using the three-dot notation, `live-branch...master` or `master...live-branch`. The same holds for `--cherry-pick` and `--cherry-mark`. However, if there's a particular commit that fixes a particular bug, @TimBiegeleisen is right, `git bisect` is the way to find it.

Comment: `--cherry-pick` works on symmetric-difference slices, three dots, `live-branch...master`, not the one-sided-difference two-dot slices.

Comment: @torek I think you just answered my question, I didn't do the three-dot notation

Comment: @jthill, what is a symmetric-difference slice?

Comment: It shows commits on both branches, omitting only commits that are in both histories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Expanding comment to answer)

I think you may want `--cherry`, which is a synonym for `--right-only --cherry-mark --no-merges` (see the `git log` or `git rev-list` documentation), or the same with `--cherry-pick` (as you tried) instead of `--cherry-mark`.  These require using the symmetric difference or three-dot notation, i.e., `live-branch...master`.

When using `--left-right` with the three-dot notation, you get commit hashes annotated with `<` if they are on the "left side" and with `>` if they are on the "right side".  Remember here that the symmetric difference of two sets means *elements that are members of either set, but not of the union of both sets*.  When applied to Git branches, we get this:

```
    (left side)    (right-side)
    live-branch       master

            *         *
            |         |
            *         X'
            |         |
            :         :
            |         |
            X         *
             \       /
              \     /
               \   /
                \ /
                 *
                 |
                 :
```

where each `*` or uppercase letter represents some commit.  The two branches come together at some point, so `left...right` looks at all the commits "above" the join, and summarily excludes all those below it.  (The join point is also excluded, since it's in both sets, although `--boundary` re-includes it.)

That's fine, but we want to know *which commits are left-side commits*, and of course the same for right-side commits.  Then, using `--cherry` or `--cherry-pick` or `--cherry-mark`, we get Git to analyze the *patch equivalence* of each commit on the left and right sides.  If two different commit hashes have the same computed `git patch-id`, meaning one was probably cherry-picked from another, they get linked together.  For instance in the diagram above, X and X' are "the same" so they are linked.

The behavior of the various `--cherry` options is to use these markings in various ways.  You are looking for commits that are present in `master` but not present in `live-branch`, so after marking pairs, you want only right side (`master`) commits that have no corresponding left-side (`live-branch`) commits.  Using `--cherry-mark`, you get to see them with markings; with `--cherry-pick`, Git will drop the marked/paired ones entirely.